# get image output by KineticJS in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, kineticjs

I'm using kineticJS to make a chart, so it's an html page that generates a chart drawing in a Div.   in php, I want to include an image of that chart in a pdf I'm generating.   KineticJS can convert the canvas to an image, but how can I get that image in a php script?

what I want is something like

```
<?php
  $html="<img src='graph.html?x=20'></img>";
  pdf->AddHTML($html);
  $pdf->output();
?>
```

I'm a little bit lost on how I should be doing this.  Ideally, the pdf should also embed the image.  I'm not asking about the pdf stuff. I'm asking basically how you can get an image generated from KineticJS into a php script, as a base64 data or whatever.

do I need something like phantomJS running in order to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the toDataURL function to get the image and then upload it to php

```
stage.toDataURL({
    callback: function(dataUrl) {
        /*
         * here you can do anything you like with the data url.
         * In this tutorial we'll just open the url with the browser
         * so that you can see the result as an image
         */
         window.open(dataUrl);
     }
});
```

See http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-stage-data-url-with-kineticjs/

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but what does "upload it to php" mean?  report.php runs, and it calls graph.html.  but what should that call look like, and what do I do with the dataURL in graph.html to "output it" so php can get it?

Comment: Mmm the image is inside graph.html? If so, i don't see how can you get the image directly from there. src="graph.html" has no sense, you are pointing what should be an image to an html file. You should pass an actual image url or base64 encoded image.

Comment: graph.html has kineticjs code to render a graph.    I need that graph as an image in report.php.   I could also make graph.html output the dataurl, but again, it has to RUN.  that's why I'm thinking I need phantomjs

Comment: I used phantomjs which runs a short script that calls graph.html with parameters and renders it to a base64 image.   The process takes 1 second so it's reasonable for the situation I'm using it for.